# SQLAlchemy won't connect to a remote mysql server database

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

A script needs to connect to a remote DB.

Here is the error that is raised:

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, u"Access denied for user 'root'@'my-ipaddress-from-isp-goes-here.client.mchsi.com' (using password: YES)")

Here is my connection setting:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:password'
                               '@server-ip:3306/database-name')
```

Scenario: This is a Raspberry Pi that is parsing scraped data that I'm storing locally and then updating at the same time to a remote server, that I'm now trying to configure.

Here's what I tried:

Followint instructions from: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-remote-database-to-optimize-site-performance-with-mysql

editing /etc/mysql/my.cnf
and under [mysqld] commenting out

> bind-address        = your_database_IP

Which got me at least denied user instead of refused connection. Any suggestions on how I can get this to work? SSH works but I just need a remote connection I can make through my Python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, trial and error. Turns out I had to grant previlages using my isp's root name using 'test' for both the user and database name:

```
CREATE USER 'test'@'my-ip-address.client.mchsi.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
```

then

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'test'@'my-ip-address.client.mchsi.com';
```